# Using private (insecure) docker registry with minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kustomize

I have a private registry with several images on it and I have it configured it inside the docker daemon:

```
{
  "log-level": "warn",
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "10m",
    "max-file": "5"
  },
  "insecure-registries" : [ "192.168.50.60:5000" ]
}
```

It is worth pointing out that this registry does not require any authentication - it's open in my home network to anyone connected. And I am able to pull images from it without issues. Now I updated my kustomization.yaml to use that registry:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

components:
- ../common

resources:
- ../../../manifests/components/dm

configMapGenerator:
- name: app
  envs:
  - environment.properties
  behavior: merge

patchesStrategicMerge:
- patch_volumes.yaml

replicas:
- name: app
  count: 1

images:
- name: image
  newName: 192.168.50.60:5000/dmlocal
  newTag: 0.0.1
```

However whenever I try to apply it, the image is not being pulled:

```
tom in ~/cluster/envs/local/dmlocal on main ● ● λ kubectl get pods | grep dmlocal
dmlocal-app-56ccf9ff45-mbw6x            0/1     ErrImagePull   0              2s
dmlocal-app-674ccdc56-qkn5m             1/1     Running            18 (18h ago)   3d23h
tom in ~/cluster/envs/local/dmlocal on main ● ● λ kubectl logs dmlocal-app-56ccf9ff45-mbw6x
Error from server (BadRequest): container "app" in pod "dmlocal-app-56ccf9ff45-mbw6x" is waiting to start: image can't be pulled
```

Also worth pointing out that I don't have any logs in the private registry. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. For those facing something similar:

```
$ minikube start --insecure-registry="host:port"
```